# Increase row height and center, but only the first row

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabu

I have a table, built using the `tabu` package.

My code currently looks like below. The `\\[5ex]` *does* increase the row height, but the contents of the third cell is aligned top instead of middle (notice the `X[c,m]` definition). The `\arraystretch` changes the height of all the rows, but I only want to increase the height of only the first one.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabu} to 0.5\linewidth {| X[c,m] | X[c,m] | X[c,m] |}
            \hline
            \textbf{First column} & \textbf{Second Column} & \textbf{Third Column} \\[5ex] \hline
            \hline

            1 & 0x1 & 01 \\ \hline
            2 & 0x2 & 02 \\ \hline
            3 & 0x3 & 03 \\ \hline
            4 & 0x4 & 04 \\ \hline
            5 & 0x5 & 05 \\ \hline
            6 & 0x6 & 06 \\ \hline
            7 & 0x7 & 07 \\ \hline
            8 & 0x8 & 010 \\ \hline
            9 & 0x9 & 011 \\ \hline
            10 & 0xa & 012 \\ \hline

        \end{tabu}
    \end{center}

    \caption{Example of another short table, but smaller and centered.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll admit it is not pretty, but I placed top rules `\tr` before each 1st-row column and a bottom rule `\br` after each 1st-row column.

Trying to accomplish it with a single rule caused inter-word vertical space to appear.  And trying to do it in one rather than three columns caused a disparity between the column positioning.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tabu}
\newcommand\tr{\rule{0pt}{4.5ex}}
\newcommand\br{\rule[-3ex]{0pt}{3ex}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabu} to 0.5\linewidth {| X[c,m] | X[c,m] | X[c,m] |}
            \hline
            \tr\textbf{First column}\br & \tr\textbf{Second Column}\br &
            \tr\textbf{Third Column}\br \\ \hline
            \hline

            1 & 0x1 & 01 \\ \hline
            2 & 0x2 & 02 \\ \hline
            3 & 0x3 & 03 \\ \hline
            4 & 0x4 & 04 \\ \hline
            5 & 0x5 & 05 \\ \hline
            6 & 0x6 & 06 \\ \hline
            7 & 0x7 & 07 \\ \hline
            8 & 0x8 & 010 \\ \hline
            9 & 0x9 & 011 \\ \hline
            10 & 0xa & 012 \\ \hline

        \end{tabu}
    \end{center}

    \caption{Example of another short table, but smaller and centered.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]